# I keep getting an error when trying to create a database in my Django Project

Tags: django, database, sqlite, migration

I deleted my database and migration files with the exception of init on purpose, I wanted to start fresh.

Using these commands:

- `find . -path "*/migrations/*.py" -not -name "__init__.py" -delete`
- `find . -path "*/migrations/*.pyc"  -delete`

I then dropped the database. Commands did their job, deleted all the migrations files necessary

I then went on to create the table again:

```
python3 manage.py makemigrations
```

I get this error:

```
return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: auctions_category
```

Things I've tried:
`python3 manage.py syncdb` (same error)
`python3 manage.py migrate --run-syncdb` (same error)

Comment: Would having an error in logic in my models.py cause this problem? I did have to use things like foreign keys and many to many relationships which I am trying to understand and only thing I can think of that may cause something to go off

Comment: One time comment your all `models`,`forms` ,`urls` etc. Then run this command.

Comment: It's not very feasible since I have so many calls to the models, including html, views, compiler just keeps screaming but I mean I guess last alternative. I'll start by commenting out my entire category model since that's what the compiler is yelling about

Comment: Try deleting entire migration folder. Create a new package with name migrations(that includes __init__.py), then run makemigrations and migrate.